# Is the equation $i = 1/i$ true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

With simple algebra it can be seen that by multiplying both sides of the equation, $i = 1/i$ by $i$ that we receive $-1 = 1$, which obviously is not true. I am puzzled, however, because I cannot find the fault in the following logic.

Because $i = \sqrt{-1}$, the original equation

$i = 1/i$

Can also be written as

$\sqrt{-1} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}$

Since $1 \cdot 1 = 1$, then $1 = \sqrt{1}$, therefore

$\sqrt{-1} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}}$

This can be rewritten as

$\sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{-1}} = \sqrt{-1}$

Where is the error in my calculations, and if there are none, then what is the correct answer? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The equality $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ only holds for *postive real numbers*. You cannot go from $\sqrt{1}/\sqrt{-1}$ to $\sqrt{1/-1}$.  This is the same as the non-valid "proof" that $1=-1$: $1 = \sqrt{1} = \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} = ii = i^2=-1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That sounds like an answer there.

Comment: There are two issues. (A) your argument is upside down and you are really saying $\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{\frac1{-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}}$.  (B) the second equality is dubious in complex arithmetic and it depends how you define the square-root function

Comment: Writing $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is one of the worst ideas one could have. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit#Proper_use).

Comment: In addition to Arturo’s comment, note that you can fix your calculation by considering square root as a multivalued function, i.e. $\sqrt 1=\{\pm1\}$, $\sqrt {-1}=\{\pm i \}$.

Comment: @Sandejo: It's a repeat (finally found a target), and as such, should not be answered, but rather closed as a duplicate.

Comment: It is clear that $\sqrt{\dfrac1{-1}}=\sqrt{-1}=i$. But $\dfrac{\sqrt1}{\sqrt{-1}}$ should be evaluated by multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator (to make it real), giving $\dfrac{\sqrt1}{\sqrt{-1}}=\dfrac{\sqrt1(-\sqrt{-1})}{\sqrt{-1}(-\sqrt{-1})}=-\dfrac i{i(-i)}=-\dfrac i1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin For being a little more rigorous we can say equality holds only for *non-negative* real numbers..

Comment: Mistake 1: $i$ can not be rewritten as $\sqrt{-1}$.  We have $i^2=-1$ but we also have $(-i)^2=-1$ but we have defined *what* $\sqrt{-1}$ *means* and whether it applies to $i$ or $-i$. Mistake 2: $1\cdot 1=1$ does *not* imply $1 = \sqrt 1$. We also have $(-1)(-1)=1$ and just knowing $1^2 =1$ is not enough to say $\sqrt 1=1$.  We have to *distinctly* point out that we define it as $1$ and *not* as $-1$.  Mistake 3:  We have no reason to believe that $\frac {\sqrt a}{\sqrt b} = \sqrt{\frac ab}$. There are two possible values for each $\sqrt{}$ term and we have no idea which ones we are applying.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, my school book says, I must write $i^2=-1$. But, I remember that, in the site high rep( gold badge user in calculus, real-complex analysis)said me, this is correct and nice to write $i=\sqrt {-1}$...

Comment: @lonestudent TheSilverDoe may have been overstating it when they say "Writing i=−1−−−√ is one of the worst ideas one could have"  But, seriously, it is a *really* badly misleading statement. Anyone told you that it is "correct" and "nice" I advise you to forget it immediately.  Doing so seems to nearly *ALWAYS* lead to these irritating and frustrating "$1 = \sqrt{1} = \sqrt{(-1)\times (-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\times \sqrt{-1} = i\times i = i^2 = -1$: Huh?" errors that should just be avoiding by noting *ALL* non-zero numbers have *two* square roots and we can't do this stuff as though there is only one.

Comment: I'm seconding @TheSilverDoe's linke to <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit#Proper_use">Wikipedia</a>.  This explains this *very* clearly and succinctly and does this *exact* question.